# Agregar texto a una figura geometrica THREE JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

Tengo esta funcion en donde creo una esfera pero a esa esfera me gustaria ponerle un texto pero que sea propia de la esfera

```
function init(){
  //Creation de contructor
  Render.setSize(800,600);
  //Add render in Div
  var re = document.getElementById('render');
  re.appendChild(Render.domElement);
  //Creation de la camera
  camera.position.z = 100;
  scene.add(camera);
  //Creation of form with vertices and vectors
  load_model();
  //Load mouse controls
  control = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, Render.domElement)
}

function load_model(){
  //Creation of the form
  geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10,32,32);

  material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xFF0000});
  form = new  THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
  scene.add(form);
}
```

Saben si es posible hacerlo y cual es la funcion

Comment: Añadir texto... ¿flotando encima? ¿como una textura? ¿Al lado?

Comment: Asi se hace con la textura?, si eso quiero que este flotando dentro o a lado de la figura

Comment: Sabes que funcion se usa para ponerlo flotando encima de la figura?